# Spotify logout on android

Tags: java, android, spotify

i have this code to log in to spotify in my app. I using the offical spotify lib.

```
public void spotifyLoginBtnClicked(View v){

    //start the authentication for spotify
    AuthenticationRequest.Builder builder = new AuthenticationRequest.Builder(clientID, AuthenticationResponse.Type.TOKEN, redirectURI);
    builder.setScopes(new String[]{"user-read-private", "streaming"});
    AuthenticationRequest request = builder.build();

    // open LoginActivity
    AuthenticationClient.openLoginActivity(this, activityIdentification, request);
}
```

Im wondering now how i can create a logout button. Because once logged in, if i press the login button again, it just returns. So i'am unable to change the user. I havent found anything in the java doc.

Comment: you don't know how to do onClick? google "android xml onClick" and you will find it

Comment: i dont know how to perform a logout for the currently logged in spotify user. The button press is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

I just found this [document](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/android-sdk-authentication-guide/) which looks similar to the code you pasted for logging in.

In there it mentions a few methods for logging the user out but I think the main block of code you will need is:

```
To log out and clear all stored tokens, use the AuthenticationClient#clearCookies method. Both Spotify and Facebook tokens will be removed.
```

I would go and check that article I linked above as there is edge cases that might be important for your project.

Happy Coding!

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. This only seems to work if the login was performed via webbrowser, not with the AuthenticationClient.

Comment: Looking at the documentation a little more it looks like might have implemented a call back method as well. That will be storing the access token. You will also need to clear that. Have a look at this solution for a full login and logout example: https://github.com/pmwisdom/cordova-spotify-plugin/blob/master/src/android/CDVSpotify.java